# Angular 2 *ngFor items count outside the loop

Tags: angular, count, ngfor

I am a novice in angular and I have a silly problem, how can I show actual number of items outside *ngFor loop ?

I'm using filter and pagination pipes like this

`*ngFor="let item of items| filterBy: ['name','category']: queryString | paginate: config; let i = index; let c = count"`

I know that there is a variable 'count' but of course it is available only in that loop, how can I get this variable in component, do I need to create new component, put it in that loop and pass 'count' through directives or there is some simpler, cleaner way?

Comment: get its length and save it in a variable and use it?

Comment: You should avoid using filter pipes. Filter in the controller instead and save it to a variable which you display. The you can just display the length of that array.

Comment: You have a problem _because_ you're using pipes to manipulate data. Don't do it. Business logic belongs to your code.

Comment: hm.. but pipes are cool :) ok. moving filtering to component is probably good solution, thanks

Comment: I agree with the suggestions of not using filtering pipe. There is a mention of it also in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe :)

Answer (score 4):

Using RxJS Subject worked for me.

In the component create a variable to hold the count i.e. `filterCount` and create a RxJS `Subject` for type `number`.
Have `subscription` to unsubscribe the `Observable` on `OnDestroy`

```
filterCount = 0;
filteredCountSubject = new Subject<number>();
subscription: Subscription;
```

subscribe to the `filteredCountSubject` on `OnInit` lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.filteredCountSubject.subscribe((count) => {
        this.filterCount = count;
    });
}
```

In Template, You can display the count using `filterCount` wherever you want in the template. using

```
<div>{{filterCount}}</div>
```

And send the `filteredCountSubject` as parameter to the `filterBy` pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items| filterBy: ['name','category']: queryString: filteredCountSubject  | paginate: config; let i = index; let c = count"></div>
```

In `transform` method of the `filterBy` pipe, Do `filteredCountSubject.next` with the count of filtered array. i.e.

```
transform(items: Array<any>, filterConfig: FilterCofig): Array<any> {
    // Arguments sent from HTML.
    const args = arguments;

    // CODE TO FILTER ITEMS BASED ON PARAMETERS.

    // Get the "filterredCountSubj" from arguments.
    // Remember that the argument index of "filteredCountSubject" is 3. As "items" is first argument.
    const filterredCountSubj = args[3];
    if (filterredCountSubj) {
        filterredCountSubj.next(items.length);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked great for me thanks! I was able to simplify it a bit by just async piping the subject instead of storing the count in a separate property

Answer (score 0):

**You could build a solution without Rxjs **
consider you have array of items

- use the ngFor directive inside the ngIf directive then you can easily get the count of the filtered array

```
<ng-container *ngIf= " (items | searchFile: 'searchItem') as filteredItems">
  {{filteredItems.length}}
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
     {{items}}
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```